# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\images\login3.png'. at htmlparser.Parse(sr); for itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF in ASP.NET C# using `itextsharp`.
It gives error of  `C:\images\login3.png`. at  `htmlparser.Parse(sr);`

I don't have any image named `login3.png`, I don't understand.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

}

Comment: This `C:\images\login3.png` its definitely not an error. Please update your question with the actual full error message. Or preferably a `Stacktrace`. Also, take a look at this similar question to help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414637/itextsharp-htmlworker-parsehtml-tablestyle-and-pdfstamper

Comment: I can't find any other error

Comment: Wrap the code of that method within a `try/catch` like so : `try { .... } catch(Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e); }` - Read this article to learn more on debugging. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788 , and this http://www.dotnetperls.com/debug-write

Comment: At a total guess, is your request being redirected to a login page as you are not authenticated?

Comment: we're going to need to see the actual error text, word for word, then... otherwise we're just guessing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in the html there is code pulling an image from that filepath, but since you don't have that file on your computer the parser can't pull its image. Make sure you have all the resources required by the html page or remove the references to images from the html, then try again.

EDIT: For some reason when I try to add a comment it just takes me to the top of the page :(
Is it the exact same error message? Please copy and paste the error message exactly. If it is the same login3.png giving you a problem, the page might have more than one reference and maybe you removed only one of them. Do a search for all image tags `<img` and see if there might be more. If the HTML is dynamically generated at runtime, you might insert a line to write the html to a file so you can analyze it. Something like `File.WriteAllLines("C:\html.txt",hw.Text);`, or however you would get the html text from the `hw` object.