# iTextSharp : HTML to PDF changing font

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext, html-to-pdf

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    pnlchecklist.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 25.0F, 25.0F, 25.0F, 25.0)
    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
    pdfDoc.Open()
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.End()
```

HI, pnlchecklist is my asp.net Panel which contain a HTML table and asp.net Gridview. I'm able to export them to pdf but I want to change the font family, font size and padding of the pdf.

I had done many researches but still can't get a correct way.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding iTextSharp and HTML rendering, this answer is very useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8419929/1741167